# Calling C++/CLI static member of public ref class from C#

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli, managed

I'm having trouble implementing the correct way to use this prototype implemented in C + + / CLI using CSharp.

C++/CLI implementation:

```cpp
// MyClassLib.h
#pragma once
using namespace System;

namespace MyClassLib 
{
    public ref class MyClass
    {
    public:
        int Increment(int number);
        static int SIncrement(int number);
    };
}
```

```cpp
// This is the main DLL file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MyClassLib.h"

namespace MyClassLib
{
    int MyClass::Increment(int number)
    {
        return number+1;
    }
    int MyClass::SIncrement(int number)
    {
        return number+1;
    }
}
```

Usage implementation:

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using MyClassLib;

namespace UseClassLib
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("MyClassLib.dll")]
        public static extern int SIncrement(int number);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass mc = new MyClass();

            int number = 1;
            number = mc.Increment(number); // increment ok

            number = SIncrement(number); // System.EntryPointNotFoundException here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`number = MyClass.SIncrement(number);`
and no P/Invoke

Answer (score 4):

`DllImportAttribute` is for **NATIVE** imports. Your C++/CLI class is not native (`ref class`) so you do not have to import that in this way. Simply add a reference to MyClassLib.dll and use it as a standard, normal, simple .NET class (call `MyClass.SIncrement()` like you would do with a C# class).